# Creating a new iOS project using Core Data and I cannot find the managedObjectModel variable in the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Hi I'm watching the Stanford CS193p iOS 9 Core Data lecture

A new iOS project is created with Core Data and copies the AppDelegate's Core Data part to the other project.

The question is when I create a new project with Core Data it's AppDelegate only has the two methods and a variable (see the screenshot).

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QS97.png)

I cannot find the `managedObjectModel` variable.

Do I have to implement this myself?

I'm using Xcode 8.0

Answer (score 0):

I found out that swift3 using
persistentContainer.viewContext

Comment: Not Swift 3. That's iOS 10.